# How do I find a single pooled effect size for a meta-analysis using metafor in R?

Tags: r, metafor

I'm doing a meta-analysis and attempting to find a pooled effect size for two different groups (differentiated by 'study' variable) in order to compare the effects. I'm using the metafor package in R. My current code is producing estimates for every study, rather than a pooled effect. How can I fix my code to find a pooled effect size?

res.re <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ study + focus +1, random = ~ focus | study, rho=1/2,
                 data=dat, slab=paste0(study, focus))
res.re

I expect the output to provide a single pooled estimate for all of the studies, but it is providing an estimate for all of the studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add `study` as a moderator. So just use `mods = ~ focus` (and you can also leave out the `+1` since this gets added automatically by default).